# Vuejs component in component :class="active" [for hour in days]

Tags: vue.js, components

I am new here and I am cant make this problem.

I am trying to make time picker for day (for each day i generate hours [ 8, 9, 10, ... ,16]

My code looks like:

DayPicker.vue

```
<time-picker
    v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="index"
    :day="day"
></time-picker>
```

TimePicker.vue

```
    <hour-picker
        v-for="(key, hour) in day.hours" 
        :key="hour + 'clock'"
        :hour="hour"
        @select="selectHour"
    ></hour-picker>
```

So I got something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQR7g.png)

Everything is working fine with props and $emit I can catch selected date and time, but I cant make how to add active class just from one clicked time. Problem is if I click time in other day, I got two times (in two days) with active class.

Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you do not want to have multiple active elements over several days. I guess the most straightforward approach would be to reset all selected hours **first** and afterward setting your **new** selected hour, like this:

```
<hour-picker
  v-for="(key, hour) in day.hours" 
  :key="hour + 'clock'"
  :hour="hour"
  @select="selectHour(hour)"></hour-picker>
```

```
selectHour (selectedHour) {
  // I: Reset all previously selected hours
  this.days.forEach(day => {
    day.hours.forEach(hour => hour.selected = false)
  })
  // II: Set your currently selected hour to selected
  selectedHour.selected = true
}
```

Since I do not know what property you are using to determine the `selected` option, this is just a small example how it could look like.

Comment: Thank you Tommy very much. It is working now perfectly. The problem was, that I was trying make it with binding class, but it much more logic make it as you suggest - with checking "if selected = true".